# In pandas combine outer json with nested json and create new dataframe

Tags: python, json, pandas

```
json_str = '[
{
"name": "t1",
"props": [
  {
    "abc": 10012,
    "def": "OBJECT"
  },
  {
    "abc": 999123,
    "def": "SUBJECT"
  }
],
"id": 1,
"title": "king"
},
{
"name": "t2",
"props": [
  {
    "abc": 789456,
    "def": "PRODUCT"
  }
],
"id": 2,
"title": "queen"
}
]'
```

Using above JSON, I want to create one dataframe that expands the `props` list and concats to main json columns.

In the end end I want to end up with these columns in df:

`id,title,name,abc,def`

With rows:

`1,king,t1,10012,OBJECT`

`1,king,t1,999123,SUBJECT`

`2,queen,t2,789456,PRODUCT`

When I try this:

```
jdata = json.loads(json_str)
pd.concat([pd.DataFrame(jdata), pd.DataFrame(list(jdata['props']))], axis=1).drop('props', 1)
```

I get this error:

> list indices must be integers or slices, not str

Also tried this:

```
jdata=json.loads(json_str)
pd.concat([pd.DataFrame(jdata), pd.DataFrame([pd.json_normalize(jdata, "props", errors="ignore", record_prefix="")])], axis=1).drop('props', 1)
```

throws this error:

> Must pass 2-d input. shape={values.shape}

Also tried this:

```
result = pd.json_normalize(jdata, 'props', errors="ignore", record_prefix="props.")
result2 = pd.json_normalize(jdata, errors="ignore", record_prefix="tmpl.")
df = pd.concat([result, result2], axis=1).drop('props', 1)
```

No error thrown here, but the `concat` doesn't line up the two df's. The rows are out of sync.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: is it a string or json data?

Comment: it's json data after json.loads(json_str)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that `pd.json_normalize` is probably the way to go, with a couple minor tweaks: first [`explode`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.explode.html) the `props` column to get one row per value in the array, and then use `apply(pd.Series)` to turn the dictionaries into their own columns:

```
# I think you already did this, but start by turning the str into proper json
>>> jdata = json.loads(json_str)
>>> result = pd.json_normalize(jdata).explode("props")   
>>> result[["abc", "def"]] = result.props.apply(pd.Series) 
>>> df = result[["id", "title", "name", "abc", "def"]]

>>> df

   id  title name     abc      def
0   1   king   t1   10012   OBJECT
0   1   king   t1  999123  SUBJECT
1   2  queen   t2  789456  PRODUCT
```

**Edit**: As per your comment, you can change things around a bit to make it work without having to explicitly refer to the columns, except for `props`:

```
>>> jdata = json.loads(json_str)
>>> result = pd.json_normalize(jdata).explode("props")   
>>> result2 = result.pop("props").apply(pd.Series)
>>> df = pd.concat([result, result2], axis=1)

  name  id  title     abc      def
0   t1   1   king   10012   OBJECT
0   t1   1   king  999123  SUBJECT
1   t2   2  queen  789456  PRODUCT
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, much appreciated! This is good, but is there a way to do this without referring to attribute names, except may the "props" attribute?

Comment: @A.G. I tried to do that in an edit, is that along the lines of what you were thinking?

Answer (score 3):

You could use [json_normalize](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.json_normalize.html) to simplify the extraction; for each `record_path` there will be an associated `meta`:

```
json_normalize(data = jdata, 
               record_path = 'props', 
               meta = ['name', 'id', 'title']
              )
 
      abc      def name id  title
0   10012   OBJECT   t1  1   king
1  999123  SUBJECT   t1  1   king
2  789456  PRODUCT   t2  2  queen
```

Comment: Much better than my (now deleted) answer! +1

Comment: I like you deleted answer and it works perfectly!! The thing with this one is again it refers to property names. If I could upvote deleted answers, I would :)

Comment: yes, @sacuL, I think you should undelete it, since that is what the OP prefers